# Increment & decrement with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve with JavaScript (if, else if, else) increment and decrement to 10 with only 1 button. 1 button on click goes from 0 to 10 (0,1,2,3,4,5...10) and when it reaches 10 if I continue clicking it starts to decrement (10, 9, 8, 7...0) How can I achieve this? I am a beginner. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add a button to a page, add a click event and inside the click event handler, check if the number is < 10, then increment else decrement. Keep the number outisde of the click event handler.

Comment: @adiga That alone won't do, then it'll just ping pong between 9 and 10. You need another variable `direction = 'asc'`. If that's `asc`, increment, else decrement. When you hit 10, set `direction = 'desc'`. When you hit 0, set it to `asc` again…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Steps

1. Create an HTML element to show the number (like `p` for example) and the button to be clicked in HTML.
2. Select the `button` in JavaScript and add an `onclick` handler to increment/decrement a number according to your logic.
3. Select the HTML element that shows the number that is being changed in JavaScript and update its content anytime the number is updated.

Refer to the code snippet below.

```js
let currentNumber = 0;
let isIncreasing = true;
const showNumberP = document.querySelector('#show-number');
const updateButton = document.querySelector('#update-button');

showNumberP.textContent = currentNumber;
updateButton.onclick = () => {
  if (isIncreasing) {
    currentNumber++;
    if (currentNumber == 10) isIncreasing = false;
  } else {
    currentNumber--;
    if (currentNumber == 0) isIncreasing = true;
  }
  showNumberP.textContent = currentNumber;
}
```

```html
<p id="show-number"></p>
<button id="update-button">Update</button>
```

Comment: Using two separate variables `isIncreasing` and `isDecreasing` is superfluous, a single boolean value would do just fine…

Comment: The `currentNumber >= 0` and `currentNumber <= 10` check is also superfluous and can be omitted.

Comment: okay thanks for pointing out, I've updated accordingly

Comment: I'm glad it helped you.

Please accept as the answer @Boboswae